# aaptOptions in Android Gradle Plugin - noCompress

Tags: android, gradle, android-sdk-tools, aapt, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using version 0.6.1 of the Gradle plugin and aaptOptions appears to ignore when I tell it not to compress. We pre-compress all PNG's to speed up the build process (on the server we build with takes ~10 minutes/build) so I added below code to the build.gradle only to have png's still running through compression.

```
aaptOptions {
   noCompress 'png'
}
```

Comment: related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934333/how-can-i-use-android-aaptoptions

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the "noCompress" option is for other assets like text files.

The aapt command you're looking to disable is called "crunch". Although I'm not sure how to disable the crunching in the Gradle plugin.