# Exclude specific files from the assets folder in Android Studio build

Tags: android, apk, assets

I've got an assets folder for my Android game that is also shared by its Windows port. I'd like to exclude specific PNG files from being included in the Android build. I've tried adding:

```
    aaptOptions {
     ignoreAssetsPattern "Images/Chooser/Scenarios/scenarios_flags.png"
}
```

within my:

```
android {}
```

section in my build.gradle file to exclude assets/Images/Chooser/Scenarios/scenarios_flags.png, but the PNG file still seems to be included in the built .apk file.

Comment: That does not very much look like a pattern.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934333/how-can-i-use-android-aaptoptions

Comment: I tried ignoreAssetsPattern "Images/Chooser/Scenarios/*.png" but that didn't work either

Comment: That does not look very much like a pattern i saw in the link i provided.

Comment: Ahh, looks like Android Studio wasn't happy with me putting in a specific path. Changing it to just:

ignoreAssetsPattern "scenarios_flags.png"

seems to find it in the sub-folder and now it's not added to the .apk, so all good now!

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, looks like Android Studio wasn't happy with me putting in a specific path. Changing it to just:

```
ignoreAssetsPattern "scenarios_flags.png"
```

seems to find it in the sub-folder and now it's not added to the .apk, so all good now!